# How to extract values of a wrapper class passed as parameters to a apex class method

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I have created a wrapper class as below -

```
public with sharing class GenerateData {
    public class Person{
        String name;
        String addressStreet;
        String addressCity;
        String addressState;
        String addressZip;
        String phone;        
    }
}
```

Now I want to have an instance of the person class to be sent over to another class method and get the values. The dot notation below gives me this error **Variable is not visible: GenerateData.Person.name**

```
public static String getDetails(GenerateData.Person p) {
    System.debug(vet);
    String name = p.name;

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dot notation is correct, and using the fully qualified type name `GenerateData.Person` as your parameter type is also correct.

The thing that you missed here (as the error may suggest) is specifying the *visibility modifier* (a.k.a. an access modifier) for your inner class's member variables.

It needs to be

```
public with sharing class GenerateData {
    public class Person{
        public String name;
        public String addressStreet;
        public String addressCity;
        public String addressState;
        public String addressZip;
        public String phone;        
    }
}
```

From [the relevant documentation on access modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm), emphasis mine

> **By default, a method or variable is visible only to the Apex code within the defining class. Explicitly specify a method or variable as public in order for it to be available to other classes in the same application namespace (see Namespace Prefix)**. You can change the level of visibility by using the following access modifiers:
>
> - private
>
>   - **This access modifier is the default**, and means that the method or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it’s defined. If you don’t specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.

Comment: Thanks @Derek F